# Nested Loops Patterns

Tags: java, loops, nested

So yeah, I'm now working on nested loops but I think I'm stuck on somewhere because my desired output is:

```js
*
**
***
**
*
```

And here's my code:

```js
    //intro here
    int x = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        x = var.nextInt();
        for(int a = 1; a <= x; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b <= x - a; b++){
                System.out.print("");
            }
            for(int c = 0; c < a; c++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

but the output happening was:

```js
*
**
***
```

I don't know now what to do, does it need another `for` with a `d--` or something?

Comment: Use a debugger (e.g. Chrome DevTools) to step through your code. That's the best way to understand what's going on.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int x = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    x = var.nextInt();
    for(int a = 1; a <= x; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b <= x - a; b++){
            System.out.print("");     //this code block do nothing in ur case
        }
        for(int c = 0; c < a; c++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

you can achieve the desired output by:

```
    int x = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    x = var.nextInt();
    for(int a = 1; a <= x; a++){
        for(int c = 0; c < a; c++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int a = x - 1; a > 0; a--){
        for(int c = a; c > 0; c--)
            System.out.print("*");
         System.out.print(""\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need another for loop for print decreasing number of stars. This should work well!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nested {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        x = var.nextInt();

        //create star rows from 1 to 6
        for (int a = 1; a <= x; a++) {
            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //create start rows from 5 to 1
        for (int a = x - 1; a > 0; a--) {
            for (int b = a; b > 0; b--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```